# Consumo de memoria em java

Tags: java, while

Bom dia Pessoal.

Fiz uma aplicação em java que em determinados horarios ela executa uma consulta ao banco de dados e gera um arquivo de texto.

A aplicação esta funcionando certo nos horarios que foi programado, no entanto no tempo que ela fica parada ela fica consumindo muita memoria(em torno de 1300 MB)

Acho que isso não é normal pois algumas aplicações desktops e wev que teriam de ter um consumo mais alto não chegam nem perto do que essa aplicação esta consumindo.

Se alguem tiver uma ideia do que pode ser ou alguma correção do problema segue abaixo o codigo.

```
private static String fileStream = "C:\\Users\\genesys\\Documents\\RM\\arq.txt";
//private static String fileStream = "C:\\Users\\Vostro-3300\\Desktop\\A comparar\\arq.txt";
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    boolean fim = false;

    while(fim == false){

        Calendar calendario = new GregorianCalendar();
        Date dt = calendario.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String dtF = df.format(dt);

        if(dtF.equals("06:00:00")||dtF.equals("06:00:01")||dtF.equals("06:00:02")||dtF.equals("06:00:03")){
            try{
                // função para envio de email
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }       
        }

        if(dtF.equals("18:00:01") ||dtF.equals("18:00:02")||dtF.equals("18:00:03")||dtF.equals("11:25:00")||dtF.equals("11:25:01")||dtF.equals("11:25:02")){
            try{
                Conecta c = new Conecta();
                ArrayList<Dados> lista = c.listar();

                FileWriter arq = new FileWriter(fileStream);
                PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(arq);

                print.println("CCODCOLIGADA;CODSECAO;DESCRICAO;NROCENCUSTOCONT;NOME;CODFUNCAO;NOME1;CHAPA;NOME2;DTNASCIMENTO;JORNADA;SALARIO;SEXO;DATAADMISSAO;DATADEMISSAO;STATUS;TIPOCONTRATO;DESCRICAOFUNCAO;GRAUINSTRUCAO;CPF;PISPASEP;RG;CTPS;ESTADOCIVIL;ENDERECO;BAIRRO;CIDADE;ESTADO;CEP;TELEFONE;EMAIL;TIPOADMISSAO");

                for(Dados d: lista){
                    print.println(d.getCodLigada()+";"+d.getCodSecao()+";"+d.getDescricao()+";"+d.getNroCenCustoCont()+";"+d.getNomeCent()+";"+d.getCodFuncao()+";"+d.getNomeFunc()+";"+d.getChapa()+";"+d.getNome()+";"+d.getDtNasc()+";"+d.getJornada()+";"+d.getSalario()+";"+d.getSexo()+";"+d.dtAdmissao+";"+d.getDtDemisao()+";"+d.getStatus()+";"+d.getContratoTipo()+";"+d.getCargoDesc()+";"+d.getGrauInstrucao()+";"+d.getCpf()+";"+d.getPisPasep()+";"+d.getRg()+";"+d.getNmrCtps()+";"+d.getEstadoCivil()+";"+d.getEndreco()+";"+d.getBairro()+";"+d.getCidade()+";"+d.getEstado()+";"+d.getCep()+";"+d.getTelefone()+";"+d.getEmail()+";"+d.getTipoAdmissao());
                }

                arq.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                try{
                    // função para envio de email
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }       
            }
        }else{

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não é mais simples agendar uma tarefa no SO para executar esse programa em determinados horários? Dependendo da hora, você inicializa o programa com um argumento diferente (e pode pegá-lo de `args`).

Comment: @renan pode ate ser uma opção mas futuramente vou precisar de ulgumas informações que essa ferramenta vai produzir em horarios aleatorios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que sua aplicação nunca para. A sugestão dada pelo renan é a melhor. Mas, o problema do consumo de memória pode ser resolvido com um `sleep`.

```
//Pausa por 10 segundos, por exemplo
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Comment: deu certo com o Thread.sleep(); mas ele tem um limite de uma hora. se eu quiser por exemplo que ele aguarde 10 horas eu precisaria fazer um loop nele ou existe outra maneira?

Comment: Tem sim, você vai ter que usar Threads e dentro de cada Thread tu vai ter que usar o sleep com o resultado do tempo de espera (em milisegundos) da subtração do horário que tu quer executar com o horario atual.

Comment: Não recomendo fazer muitos sleeps encadeados, isso fará com que a máquina fique em espera ocupada, isso é, você não vai poder interromper a espera. Se você deseja fazer uma espera que possa ser interrompida, use Threads nas operações e outros recursos como Syncronize, etc. Olhe este artigo> http://www.devmedia.com.br/java-threads-utilizando-wait-notify-e-notifyall/29545

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr legal vou dar uma olhada nesse material. Consegui resolver com a implementação do `Thread.sleep();` obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Você está refazendo declarações dentro do *loop.* Passe a declarar fora do *loop:*

```
final Calendar calendario = new GregorianCalendar();
final Date dt = calendario.getInstance().getTime();
final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
final String dtF = df.format(dt);

while (!fim) {
    // ...
}
```

Você não está fechando o `printWriter`.

```
try {
    Conecta c = new Conecta();
    List<Dados> lista = c.listar();

    PrintWriter print;

    try {
        print = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileStream));

        for (Dados d : lista) {
            // ...
        }
    } finally {
        print.close();
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    try {
        // função para envio de email
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Implemente a ideia do nosso colega Celso, use `sleep`.

Comment: não havia me tocado do print.close(). eu alterei o codigo para declarar as variaveis fora do loop mas mesmo isso o ganho foi bem pouco. Sabe se existe ou tem como medir quanto esta gastando cada processo?

Comment: Já ouvi falar do Apache JMeter, mas nunca mexi. http://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: Chegou a testar se o gargalo não estaria na sua classe `Conecta`? Tente comentar a linha `Conecta c = new Conecta();` e suas chamadas para ver o que acontece com o uso de memória.

Comment: Sobre a performance, leia isso: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPerformance/article.html ele fala um pouco sobre o VisualVM, nativo do java sdk, que pode ser usado para testar a performance.

Comment: @VictorT. consegui vou buscar sobre essa ferramenta e referente a classe `Conecta` ja testei e ela consome muito pouco. Depois de implementar a `Thread.sleep();` ja diminuiu bastante obrigado pela ajuda